# How to reset a Tenda TEG1224T or access its management page

Tags: networking, dhcp, switch, managed

About two weeks ago I replaced two routers (in bridge mode) and a switch with a single Tenda TEG1224T V2 (https://tendacn.com/en/product/TEG1224T.html). It was a second hand purchase on eBay. Everything worked perfectly and the network speeds have increased dramatically.

However, after about seven days of use, each device will lose connection to the internet one by one. If any of those devices have their DHCP lease is refreshed, they'll come back with a self assigned IP. Power cycling the switch will resole the issue, but and the end of the second week of service, the issue occurred again.

I have tried looking for documentation from the manufacturer on how to manage and configure the switch and come up empty handed. It's advertised that it can "be configured from any network computer through an internet browser" but there is no clue on how to do so (though they have provided the firmware file to reload if I ever figure out how to manage the device). The router providing DHCP shows no sign that the switch has obtained an IP either.

While there is a reset button on the switch, pressing it, holding it for 30 seconds, or holding it while powering on seems to have done nothing. No sign that it acknowledged that the button was even pressed.

I've tired asking for help on the Tenda forms, but after creating an account, I have not been given privileges to post any threads. I have used their support page to request help, but received no reply. I've emailed them directly and still am waiting for reply. I'm not overly keen on trying their contact number as it's a +86 number for China.

Any thoughts from the community?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve finished trawling the Tenda website and have found one other managed switch lacking a console port and administrated by a standard ethernet port. This TEG3210PV model has a user manual and it got me in my my model. This is what I did:

1. Set the DHCP settings of a client connected to the switch to the following:

   - IP: 192.168.0.2
   - Subnet: 255.255.255.0
2. Opened a browser and entered 192.168.0.1 as the address.
3. Used “admin” for the name and password.

Boom! In.

There was an additional issue where the admin page’s JavaScript seems to be broken, but I worked around that by manually unhiding the collapsed menu items from the browser’s inspector.